# Where is the "Facebook live support chat" which helps you and send your Facebook page to revision?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages

I have a problem with a Facebook page, and asking others Facebook page admins, they mentioned a "Facebook live support chat" which helps you and send your Facebook page to revision". They gave me vague indications of where it is, including links with a lot of explanations but where they chat isnt there. Some said that you need a publicity account in Facebook to have access to the chat, but I have one and I still don't find it.

Where is the "Facebook live support chat" which helps you and send your Facebook page to revision?

Answer (score -2):

![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.co m/ISSGw.jpg)